# Translating an 8 byte value in to an actual number:

Tags: c, binary, double, computer-science, endianness

I have 8 bytes which represent a number. The description I am given is:

> "Signed Little-Endian encoded eight byte integer field with eight
>   implied decimal places"

and when "scooping" the data from a file dump the eight bytes are (I have included the char representation just to make the binary clear):

- [0] = 0 ('\0')
- [1] = 86 ('v')
- [2] = 41 (')')
- [3] = 50 ('2')
- [4] = 48 ('0')
- [5] = 0 ('\0')
- [6] = 0 ('\0')
- [7] = 0 ('\0')

After looking up the endian-ness wikipedia article I think I need to start from [7] and work backwards to [0] (the file order was from [0] to [7]). But I am unsure what I need to do with the values.

Could someone help me work out what this number is (so that I could assign these 8 bytes to a double)?

Comment: Perhaps if you had some example code (unworking is fine) showing what you're trying to do, along with what the correct answer _should_ be as well as what answer your code is producing, it would be more clear what you're asking.

Comment: @mah If I could provide that I wouldnt have asked the question. The last sentence says what I am trying to do. Given these bytes- I want to create a double representation.

Comment: Ah, I knew it must have something to do with fiscal affairs. But 8 decimal places? Ok, maybe for converting between currencies...

Comment: It is a nice round number, 2070.0, if you cast `*(long long*)bytes` and multiply by 1E-8.  Clearly asking whomever generated the data is the sane approach.

Comment: @HansPassant please could you tell me exactly what you did there?! Is bytes a char[8]?! You have the correct value

Comment: Yes, just cast as I showed you.

Comment: @HansPassant would you be able to tell me what your method does different compared with the answer I accepted for this question? I didn't get the same value when I tried glglglg's answer.

Comment: His code cannot work for 8 bytes, only 4.

Comment: @HansPassant because of uintmax_t? I changed it to "long" and it still didnt work

Comment: Look at my cast again.  Notice it says `long long`?  Two, not one.

Comment: if int is 4 bytes and long is therefore 8 bytes, why should long long be used? If you put your answer listed as an official answer i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong with your assumption LE means that the first byte is the one with the lowest significance.

To portably convert this, you could use

```
uintmax_t read_le_value(char * data, size_t len)
{
    uintmax_t value = 0;
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        value |= data[i] << (8*i);
    }
    return value;
}
```

You can call this function with

```
int64_t result = read_le_value(array, sizeof array);
```

Please note that this invokes implementation-defined behaviour: on architectures which don't use the two-s complement for storing signed values, it might break.

This 64 bit value would be fine, if there wasn't another point:

> with eight implied decimal places

probably refers to the fact that it might be a fixed-point notation and that a value of `1200000000` indeed means `12.00000000`.

So you should divide the result by `1E8` (=100000000) in order to get the wanted result.

But be aware that converting to a `double` loses precision, as `double` only has 53 bits of precision.

So the value 1000000000.00000001, expressed as 100000000000000001, will be converted to 1000000000.0: if you subtract this number, you'll get 0.0, instead of .00000001 as you wanted.

Comment: Ah ok so all we're doing is writing each byte as its binary, sticking the bits from the 8 bytes together and then converting all the individual bits in to a 64 bit representation? I was worried due to the whole "implied decimal places" part.

Comment: @user997112 I added a paragraph about that.

Comment: Do you think the "signed" in "Signed Little-Endian" implies a sign bit exist in `data[7]` or someplace?  Oh I see that now in your `unintmax_t` to `int64_t` conversion in `int64_t result = read_le_value()`

Comment: @chux Yes, but that gets converted automatically on assignment of the `uintmax_t` to `int64_t`.

Comment: I think I will be ok with the loss of precision because these values represent prices so it would only be to 4 decimal places max.

Comment: Are the 64-bit types you have used standard c/c++ and not OS-specific?

Comment: @user997112 Nevertheless, I'd stick with keeping the integer values and convert them only for displaying.

Comment: @user997112 They come from C99's `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: Could I have replaced "|=" with "+="?

Comment: @user997112 Should work as well. Try out and look at the difference...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41770/discussion-between-user997112-and-glglgl)

Comment: The fact that `double` has only 53 bits of precision is not the reason that dividing by 1e8 introduces rounding error. No matter how many bits a binary floating-point format has, dividing (most numerators) by 1e8 will have some rounding error. The reason is because the base is binary, and 1e-8 is not a multiple of any power of two (including negative powers).

Comment: Unless I have missed something, the C standard does not guarantee that converting `uint64_t` to `int64_t` will work correctly when there is overflow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're not missing anything. It is implementation-defined when *value* converting an unsigned-to-signed integer type when the value is beyond the allowable representation of the target. C99-6.3.1.3-p3, "Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

Comment: @WhozCraig and Eric, thx for pointing that out. I just added a note to the answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right, that is another factor. But if I'd use, say 2**32, your concern would fall away, but mine would persist.